# Create a 24 hour vector with 60 and 1 minutes time interval in R

Tags: r

I have a firewall log file that includes date, hour, src_address, dest_address and Date.time. I want to create a 24 hour vector with 60 and 1 minutes time interval for everytime(ex;from 2018/01/01 to 2018/05/06) .Then in these intervals I want to find appearence of pair of src_address and dest_address.Lastly max of these appearence for every pair of src_address and dest_address.Here is my file;

```
                date     hour    src_address  dest_address           Date.Time

1996  2018-04-14 08:24:01    1.11.201.19 172.16.16.100 2018-04-14 08:24:01
3702  2018-04-15 12:10:27    1.119.43.90 172.16.16.100 2018-04-15 12:10:27
1154  2018-04-14 00:59:27    1.119.43.90 172.16.16.153 2018-04-14 00:59:27
2414  2018-04-14 12:33:29    1.119.43.90 192.168.1.112 2018-04-14 12:33:29
18013 2018-04-28 18:49:05   1.171.43.133   172.16.16.5 2018-04-28 18:49:05
18015 2018-04-28 18:49:05   1.171.43.133   172.16.16.5 2018-04-28 18:49:05
6903  2018-04-25 21:31:52   1.179.191.82   172.16.16.5 2018-04-25 21:31:52
11741 2018-04-27 01:08:43   1.179.191.82 192.168.1.111 2018-04-27 01:08:43
11933 2018-04-27 02:00:10   1.179.191.82 192.168.1.111 2018-04-27 02:00:10
11023 2018-04-26 21:39:39   1.179.191.82 192.168.1.112 2018-04-26 21:39:39
11175 2018-04-26 22:31:01   1.179.191.82 192.168.1.112 2018-04-26 22:31:01
13073 2018-04-27 08:24:58   1.180.72.186 172.16.16.153 2018-04-27 08:24:58
13735 2018-04-27 12:07:34   1.180.72.186 172.16.16.153 2018-04-27 12:07:34
2752  2018-04-14 19:34:53   1.202.165.40 172.16.16.153 2018-04-14 19:34:53
4046  2018-04-15 18:16:40    1.203.84.52   172.16.16.5 2018-04-15 18:16:40
4048  2018-04-15 18:18:43    1.203.84.52 192.168.1.112 2018-04-15 18:18:43
3020  2018-04-15 01:35:40    1.209.171.4 192.168.1.111 2018-04-15 01:35:40
4870  2018-04-16 05:33:42   1.214.34.114 172.16.16.100 2018-04-16 05:33:42
7025  2018-04-25 22:28:06   1.214.34.114 172.16.16.100 2018-04-25 22:28:06
4262  2018-04-15 23:31:56   1.214.34.114 172.16.16.153 2018-04-15 23:31:56
9369  2018-04-26 10:32:50   1.214.34.114 172.16.16.153 2018-04-26 10:32:50
2716  2018-04-14 18:49:30   1.214.34.114   172.16.16.5 2018-04-14 18:49:30
9563  2018-04-26 12:34:58   1.214.34.114   172.16.16.5 2018-04-26 12:34:58
1110  2018-04-14 00:27:02   1.214.34.114 192.168.1.111 2018-04-14 00:27:02
4470  2018-04-16 01:27:32   1.214.34.114 192.168.1.112 2018-04-16 01:27:32
9581  2018-04-26 12:55:39    1.55.249.92 172.16.16.153 2018-04-26 12:55:39
2970  2018-04-15 00:01:18    1.55.249.92   172.16.16.5 2018-04-15 00:01:18
15329 2018-04-27 21:53:16    1.55.249.92   172.16.16.5 2018-04-27 21:53:16
15537 2018-04-28 00:02:30    1.55.249.92   172.16.16.5 2018-04-28 00:02:30
19249 2018-04-29 06:28:04   1.71.188.254 172.16.16.100 2018-04-29 06:28:04
19243 2018-04-29 06:28:04   1.71.188.254 172.16.16.153 2018-04-29 06:28:04
19241 2018-04-29 06:28:04   1.71.188.254 172.16.16.159 2018-04-29 06:28:04
19239 2018-04-29 06:28:04   1.71.188.254   172.16.16.5 2018-04-29 06:28:04
19247 2018-04-29 06:28:04   1.71.188.254 192.168.1.111 2018-04-29 06:28:04
19245 2018-04-29 06:28:04   1.71.188.254 192.168.1.112 2018-04-29 06:28:04
6315  2018-04-25 18:56:08     1.85.18.88 172.16.16.153 2018-04-25 18:56:08
14623 2018-04-27 16:41:00     1.85.18.88 172.16.16.153 2018-04-27 16:41:00
```

And here is my expectation;

```
   src_address  dest_address max(per hour) max(per minute)
2  1.11.201.19 172.16.16.100           1       1   
3  1.119.43.90 172.16.16.100           1       1   
4  1.119.43.90 172.16.16.153           1       1   
5  1.119.43.90 192.168.1.112           1       1   
6 1.171.43.133   172.16.16.5           2       2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite a few things have to be done to get the summaries data. One can use `dplyr`, `tidyr` and `lubridate` packages to transform data.

> The approach:
>
> 1. Create `DateTime` column by uniting date and hour and converting to
>      `ymd_hms`
> 2. Group on `src_addres`, `dest_address`, and `Year-Month-Day Hour` to
>      calculate hourly occurrence
> 3. Group on `src_addres`, `dest_address`, and `Year-Month-Day Hour:Min` to calculate > per min occurrence
> 4. Group on `src_addres`, `dest_address` and summarize to get max of hourly and per min occurrence

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>% unite("DateTime", c("date","hour"), sep=" ") %>% 
  mutate(DateTime = ymd_hms(DateTime)) %>%
  group_by(src_addres, dest_address, YMD_H = format(DateTime, "%Y-%m-%d %H")) %>%
  mutate(HourlyAppearance = n()) %>%
  group_by(src_addres, dest_address, YMD_HM = format(DateTime, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")) %>%
  mutate(PerMinAppearance = n()) %>%
  group_by(src_addres, dest_address) %>%
  summarise( 'max(per hour)' = max(HourlyAppearance), 
           'max(per min)' = max(PerMinAppearance)) %>%
  as.data.frame()

#      src_addres  dest_address max(per hour) max(per min)
# 1   1.11.201.19 172.16.16.100             1            1
# 2   1.119.43.90 172.16.16.100             1            1
# 3   1.119.43.90 172.16.16.153             1            1
# 4   1.119.43.90 192.168.1.112             1            1
# 5  1.171.43.133   172.16.16.5             2            2
# 6  1.179.191.82   172.16.16.5             1            1
# 7  1.179.191.82 192.168.1.111             1            1
# 8  1.179.191.82 192.168.1.112             1            1
# 9  1.180.72.186 172.16.16.153             1            1
# 10 1.202.165.40 172.16.16.153             1            1
# 11  1.203.84.52   172.16.16.5             1            1
# 12  1.203.84.52 192.168.1.112             1            1
# 13  1.209.171.4 192.168.1.111             1            1
# 14 1.214.34.114 172.16.16.100             1            1
# 15 1.214.34.114 172.16.16.153             1            1
# 16 1.214.34.114   172.16.16.5             1            1
# 17 1.214.34.114 192.168.1.111             1            1
# 18 1.214.34.114 192.168.1.112             1            1
# 19  1.55.249.92 172.16.16.153             1            1
# 20  1.55.249.92   172.16.16.5             1            1
# 21 1.71.188.254 172.16.16.100             1            1
# 22 1.71.188.254 172.16.16.153             1            1
# 23 1.71.188.254 172.16.16.159             1            1
# 24 1.71.188.254   172.16.16.5             1            1
# 25 1.71.188.254 192.168.1.111             1            1
# 26 1.71.188.254 192.168.1.112             1            1
# 27   1.85.18.88 172.16.16.153             1            1
```

**Data:**

OP hasn't provided data in a pretty simple format. The inclusion of date and time columns has made it more difficult. Perhaps that  be reason for low response to this question. I preferred to read `date` and `time` part separately and then `unite` those to get `Date/Time`.

```
strtext <- "Sl  date hour  src_addres  dest_address  Date_t   Time_t
1996  2018-04-14 08:24:01    1.11.201.19 172.16.16.100 2018-04-14 08:24:01
3702  2018-04-15 12:10:27    1.119.43.90 172.16.16.100 2018-04-15 12:10:27
1154  2018-04-14 00:59:27    1.119.43.90 172.16.16.153 2018-04-14 00:59:27
2414  2018-04-14 12:33:29    1.119.43.90 192.168.1.112 2018-04-14 12:33:29
18013 2018-04-28 18:49:05   1.171.43.133   172.16.16.5 2018-04-28 18:49:05
18015 2018-04-28 18:49:05   1.171.43.133   172.16.16.5 2018-04-28 18:49:05
6903  2018-04-25 21:31:52   1.179.191.82   172.16.16.5 2018-04-25 21:31:52
11741 2018-04-27 01:08:43   1.179.191.82 192.168.1.111 2018-04-27 01:08:43
11933 2018-04-27 02:00:10   1.179.191.82 192.168.1.111 2018-04-27 02:00:10
11023 2018-04-26 21:39:39   1.179.191.82 192.168.1.112 2018-04-26 21:39:39
11175 2018-04-26 22:31:01   1.179.191.82 192.168.1.112 2018-04-26 22:31:01
13073 2018-04-27 08:24:58   1.180.72.186 172.16.16.153 2018-04-27 08:24:58
13735 2018-04-27 12:07:34   1.180.72.186 172.16.16.153 2018-04-27 12:07:34
2752  2018-04-14 19:34:53   1.202.165.40 172.16.16.153 2018-04-14 19:34:53
4046  2018-04-15 18:16:40    1.203.84.52   172.16.16.5 2018-04-15 18:16:40
4048  2018-04-15 18:18:43    1.203.84.52 192.168.1.112 2018-04-15 18:18:43
3020  2018-04-15 01:35:40    1.209.171.4 192.168.1.111 2018-04-15 01:35:40
4870  2018-04-16 05:33:42   1.214.34.114 172.16.16.100 2018-04-16 05:33:42
7025  2018-04-25 22:28:06   1.214.34.114 172.16.16.100 2018-04-25 22:28:06
4262  2018-04-15 23:31:56   1.214.34.114 172.16.16.153 2018-04-15 23:31:56
9369  2018-04-26 10:32:50   1.214.34.114 172.16.16.153 2018-04-26 10:32:50
2716  2018-04-14 18:49:30   1.214.34.114   172.16.16.5 2018-04-14 18:49:30
9563  2018-04-26 12:34:58   1.214.34.114   172.16.16.5 2018-04-26 12:34:58
1110  2018-04-14 00:27:02   1.214.34.114 192.168.1.111 2018-04-14 00:27:02
4470  2018-04-16 01:27:32   1.214.34.114 192.168.1.112 2018-04-16 01:27:32
9581  2018-04-26 12:55:39    1.55.249.92 172.16.16.153 2018-04-26 12:55:39
2970  2018-04-15 00:01:18    1.55.249.92   172.16.16.5 2018-04-15 00:01:18
15329 2018-04-27 21:53:16    1.55.249.92   172.16.16.5 2018-04-27 21:53:16
15537 2018-04-28 00:02:30    1.55.249.92   172.16.16.5 2018-04-28 00:02:30
19249 2018-04-29 06:28:04   1.71.188.254 172.16.16.100 2018-04-29 06:28:04
19243 2018-04-29 06:28:04   1.71.188.254 172.16.16.153 2018-04-29 06:28:04
19241 2018-04-29 06:28:04   1.71.188.254 172.16.16.159 2018-04-29 06:28:04
19239 2018-04-29 06:28:04   1.71.188.254   172.16.16.5 2018-04-29 06:28:04
19247 2018-04-29 06:28:04   1.71.188.254 192.168.1.111 2018-04-29 06:28:04
19245 2018-04-29 06:28:04   1.71.188.254 192.168.1.112 2018-04-29 06:28:04
6315  2018-04-25 18:56:08     1.85.18.88 172.16.16.153 2018-04-25 18:56:08
14623 2018-04-27 16:41:00     1.85.18.88 172.16.16.153 2018-04-27 16:41:00"

df <- read.table(text = strtext,header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: @Hüseyin Lets do one thing. All you need is `dplyr`, `tidyr` and `lubridate`. Try my answer with those 3 packages.